# Compare two lists via two property in addition to having list of unique values from third property creating new lists

Tags: c#, list, linq, data-structures

Lets say i have two collections ExampleCollection1 and ExampleCollection2.
I want to iterate via linq comparing property 'ab' and 'gh' from both collections with distinct value for xy and create a new list. I am not worried about image.

```
 var ex1List = new List<ExampleCollection1>
 {
    new ExampleCollection1 {ab = "10", gh = "200" },
    new ExampleCollection1 {ab = "10", gh = "300" },
    new ExampleCollection1 {ab = "10", gh = "400" },
    new ExampleCollection1 {ab = "10", gh = "500" },
    new ExampleCollection1 {ab = "10", gh = "600" }
 };

   var ex2List = new List<ExampleCollection2>
   {
    new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "200", xy = "5", image = "star"},
    new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "200", xy = "10", image = "moon"},
    new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "400", xy = "4", image = "globe" },
    new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "400", xy = "4", image = "earth" },//this should not be in the resulting collection as previous entry and this are same for ab, gh, and xy
    new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "600", xy = "3", image = "twinkle" }
   };
```

So, i need the final list to contain

```
var finalList = new List<ExampleCollection2>
            {
                new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "200", xy = "5", image = "star"},
                new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "200", xy = "10", image = "moon"},
                new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "400", xy = "4", image = "globe" },
                new ExampleCollection2 {ab = "10", gh = "600", xy = "3", image = "twinkle" }
            };
```

i tried but i know its incomplete. Need a way where i can iterate and get also distinct values for xy

```
 foreach (var item in ex1List)
            {
                var finalList = ex2List?.FindAll(val => val.ab != null && val.gh != null &&
                    CheckEquals(item.ab, item.gh, val.ab, val.gh)); // here need  to check for distinct values for xy too. how to do that ?

                foreach(var x in finalList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.ab + x.gh + x.xy + x.image);
                }
            }

private bool CheckEquals(<...>)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy. Try this:

```
var finalList =
(
    from ex1 in ex1List
    join ex2 in ex2List on new { ex1.ab, ex1.gh } equals new { ex2.ab, ex2.gh }
    group ex2 by ex2.xy into gex2s
    from gex2 in gex2s.Take(1)
    select gex2
).ToList();
```

That gives me:

[image: finalList]

This does rely on the order of `ex2List` to exclude `earth` over `globe`. You may need to include an `orderby` to ensure a deterministic selection.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. I can try this but I want to use my CheckEquals function to check for ab and gh as I have made them as string for example purpose but they are of custom type so how will this change when using CheckEquals??

Comment: @jamilia - Please don't change the requirements of your question in the comments of answers. Please edit your question to clarify this new requirement. Also, please provide a complete implementation of `bool CheckEquals(<...>)` that matches what you're asking for in your question. Also please include the definition of your types.